# Which data model to use to maintain every day historical data for a customer

Tags: mysql, database, cassandra

I need to maintain everyday closing balance of a customer and plot a line graph based on that balance for the last 365 days. Which data model is preferred to maintain this data ?

MySQL, Cassandra or any other databases ?

Comment: 'I need to maintain everyday closing balance of a customer' -  I disagree.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to have a table with a key [client id, data] and the value being closing balance.

The question is how do you fill that data in? You could have a running job at the day end. The big question is how to make the system reliable? If job fails and is restarted next day, will that provide data for the previous day?

Typical way of addressing this type of problem is using "event sourcing". This is a fancy way of saying that it needs to be a storage of records for every operation executed on a balance. Every add/deduct should be there, including client id and date. These records also may have "resulting balance" - which implies that last operation for a customer in a day has the closing balance as well.

At the end, you will have list of transactions and you will be able to "replay" previous event to get balances. It's your choice if you want to have actual table for daily balances per client - as it may be cheaper to look up that data instead of recalculating it every time.

In banking industry, every transaction is stored as a separate record for this specific reason - to be able to get different reports; incl. closing balances per day.